# Irrationality of a unique positive root of $\sin{x} = x^2$

Tags: trigonometry

The equation $\sin{x} = x^2$ has a unique positive real root. I wonder if there is any standard technique how to show that this number is irrational (rational), preferably a technique which works also in other similar scenarios.

I tried an inverse symbolic calculator on the numerical approximation of the root, but it didn´t find anything whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact $x$ is irrational. See [Corollary 2.7](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ov-IlIEo47cC&pg=PA21&source=gbs_toc_r&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) in Niven's book. If the root $x$ in question was rational, then $\sin(x)$ is irrational and so $\sin(x)-x^2$ could not be zero (since this would be an irrational minus a rational).

Answer (score 3):

It is known that $\sin(1)$ is transcendental (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Numbers_proven_to_be_transcendental)), and it follows that $\sin(r)$ must be irrational and even transcendental for any nonzero rational number $r$ (since there is a nontrivial algebraic relation between $\sin(r)$ and $\sin(1)$). Hence $\sin(r) = r^2$ cannot hold for any nonzero $r$.

Comment: When you say sin(1) you mean sine of 1 degree or 1 radian?

Comment: 1 radian, for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the graph of sin x and $x^2$ you will see that it intersect at two point x=0 and the equation can also be written as $\frac{e^{-ix}-e^{ix}}{2}=x^2 $  by Euler form of complex number . So other root will be irrational .

Comment: That doesn't *necessarily* hold. $x=0$ is also a solution to this (since it's just a rearrangement of the original equation) and it is not irrational

Comment: I am using $x is not n\pi$ to rearrange the equation

Comment: My last comment (deleted) was patently false, sorry. But it's not clear that every value of $\sin(x)$ s.t. $x\neq n\pi$ is irrational if $x \in \mathbb Q$. If so you should either prove it or show where it is proved.

Answer (score 0):

It can be shown that the sines and cosines of the acute angles in a pythagorean triangle are irrational.  So know if $x$ would be rational ...